# How does the Green Ranger play the Dragonzord dagger-flute?

Tags: power-rangers, mighty-morphin-power-rangers

When the Green Ranger summons the Dragonzord, he plays his dagger like a flute:

[image: playing dagger]

How can he do this when his mask appears to be solid?

[image: mask]

Comment: cheep costume design is cheep

Comment: How does the Green Ranger play the Dragonzord dagger-flute? *Wonderfully!*

Comment: Doesn't matter to him - he can't hear anyway since the helmet also lacks ear holes.

Comment: This seems to be asking for real-world science, as *everyone* who plays the flute looks like their mouth is closed and solid

Comment: The same way everyone talks despite appearing to have molded plastic over their lips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mask isn't solid. It has air holes above the mouthpiece, as can be seen in this [prop-handling video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8nWJSwkhxdI) with the original helmet. Obviously the air comes out of these holes and into the flute.

[image]

Comment: Is he blowing with his nose then? It looks likes his lips would be below those holes.

Comment: @Longshanks - I wouldn't pay too close attention. I'm pretty sure the makers of the show didn't